# How to manually define props type in vue3 with typescript

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I can do

```
defineComponent({
  props: {
    name: { type: String as PropType<string> }
  }
})
```

to tell vue3 that my `props` type is `{ name: string }`, but if I have several component have the same props type, how can I share the defination?

If I define props in :

```
const props = {
  name: String as PropType<string>
}
```

then use it like this:

```
defineComponent({
  props: props,
})
```

It won't work, the type I got in setup function of props is not right.

Answer (score 2):

this answer is purely addition to @Xinchao's answer.

one way is to destructure common props like following:

```js
// taken from @Xinchao's answer 
const commonProps = {
  name: { type: String as PropType<string> }
}

defineComponent({
  props:{
    ...commonProps,

    extra: { }

  }
})
```

another way is to write function which returns specific object like following

```js
function getStringProp(required=false) {
    return {
       type: String as PropType<string>,
       required,
       default: '',
    };
}


defineComponent({
  props:{
    name: getStringProp(true),
    nickName: getStringProp(),
    extra: { }

  }
})
```

this case specifically come handy where prop is Array or Object; where we can cast the type like following

```js
function getArrayProp<T>(required=false) {
    return {
       type: Array as PropType<T[]>,
       required,
       default: () => [],
    };
}


defineComponent({
  props:{
    options: getArrayProp<Options>(true),
    stringOptions: getArrayProp<string>(true),
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The props options provided for `defineComponent` is a plain js object solely for type annotation purpose, so you can employ whatever technics in javascript for sharing structures between objects:

```ts
// in common.ts
export const commonProps = {
  name: { type: String as PropType<string> }
}

// in your component.vue
import commonProps from "./common.ts";

defineComponent({
  props:{
    ...commonProps,

    extra: { }

  }
})
```

Answer (score -5):

If you're using the composition API with Vue 2 in preparation for switching to Vue 3, you have to use the `PropType` from that package instead of the `vue` package.

```
// Wrong for Vue 2
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api'

// Right for Vue 2
import { defineComponent, PropType } from '@vue/composition-api'
```

Comment: This was not the question, the author explit wrote "Vue3" not "Vue2"